# binding click event using images to page

Tags: jquery

I have a menu on my page which changes the source of a particular div(). The items are divs  are located in  a div called foliolist

The div where the image changes is below:

```
<div id="random"><img id="grouptabs" src="/u/i/1x0.jpg" /> </div>
```

List of items that change the div, these sit at the absolute bottom of the page

```
<div class="foliolist"><a href="/u/i/2.png"><img src="/v/r.gif"/></a></div>
<div class="foliolist"><a href="/u/i/4.png"><img src="/v/r.gif"/></a></div>
<div class="foliolist"><a href="/u/i/6.png"><img src="/v/r.gif"/></a></div>
```

Jquery code that makes it happen

```
$('.foliolist a').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('.foliolist a').css('background-color', 'transparent');  
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); 
  $('#grouptabs').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); 
});
```

List of items appear, first one gets selected by default with the code below

```
$('#bubbles > #folioholder > .foliolist > a:first').each(function(e){
  $('.foliolist').css('background-color', 'transparent'); 
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
  $('#grouptabs').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I want to add new navigation bars to give the page a better usage by adding next and previous buttons images to complement the page. These will be located on the left and right side of the page.

If the left next button is clicked the progress in the grid advances, and same for the previous button but it goes backwards.

I don't know how to approach this without looking silly so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little comment : Your last snippet of code could be replaced by `$('#bubbles > #folioholder > .foliolist > a:first').click();`

On the actual question :

You'll have to create your buttons and bind them event to retrieve the currently displayed picture to retrieve the following/previous img.

```
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
    //get current picture displayed
    var currPicSrc = $('#grouptabs').attr('src');
    var foundPic = false;
    var nextPic = "";        
    $('.foliolist a img').each(function(){
        if (foundPic) {nextPic = $(this).attr('src'); return false; }
        if ($(this).attr('src') == currPicSrc) {
            foundPic = true;
        }
    });
    if (nextPic == "") {
        nextPic = $('.foliolist:first a img').attr('src');
    }
    $('#grouptabs').attr('src', nextPic);
});

$('#btnPrev').click(function(){
    //get current picture displayed
    var currPicSrc = $('#grouptabs').attr('src');
    var foundPic = false;
    var prevPic = "";        
    $('.foliolist a img').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('src') == currPicSrc) {
            foundPic = true;
            return false;
        }
        if (!foundPic) {prevPic = $(this).attr('src'); }
    });
    if (prevPic == "") {
        prevPic = $('.foliolist:last a img').attr('src');
    }
    $('#grouptabs').attr('src', prevPic);
});
```

It's a way to do it (I'm not managing the case where you click previous on the first pic/click next on the last pic).

Another way would be to add ids to your image and toy with them (especially easy if you'd use name like `<img id="whatever1" /><img id="whatever2" /> [...]` so you could get the current pic with the number in the id and then loop over that.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, i've binded it to my images but it does get the next image rather it refreshes the page <div id="btnNext"><a href=""><img src="f.png"></a></div>. I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but not sure what it is.

Comment: `<a href="">` will refresh the page since it got no value in the href (default behavior). Try `<div id="btn_Container"><a href="#" id="btnNext">Next image</a></div>`. Also, adding a `return false;` in the .click _function_ could work too to stop this behavior, although, having an empty href is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks Kraz i've done all of it but it's not getting the image. I've even used firebug and it's not firing up with any clicks.

Comment: @Kraz you mention another method using ids this might be quicker which makes sense how would i be a ble to substitute the code you've provided.

I place an alert and the alert works but it's not finding the .foliolist a img i'm just stumped...

Comment: My answer was lacking a crucial line : the line that changed the img source (`$('#grouptabs').attr('src', nextPic);`). As for the alternate method, it would require an answer of its own. I might do that if I find the time today.

Comment: I also added looping (if no pic is found, pic the first/last). I pasted the content of my test file [here](http://pastebin.me/e8241e743c789198443efedcba01f837) (You'll have to add some picture yourself (+jquery))

Comment: @Kraz  that did thanks so much for your help. Only one more thing which i'm trying to solve. When the arrow gets the image how can i highlight the foliolist that it came from

`  $('.foliolist a').css('background-color', 'transparent');  
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');`

The code above sets all the transparent then set the selected one to white?

Comment: Since this manipulation work on your `.foliolist a click`, I suppose you want to add those to the next and prev bouton? You'll have to add them in the good place, I figured it out [and updated the pastebin](http://pastebin.me/caad807a89d65ccab2940d5d960266e2). Enjoy (it's not really cute although).

Comment: @Kraz that was the icing on the cake...Thanks so much.